# How to control the "ok" button on datePickerDialog? (Android)

Tags: android, dialog, datepickerdialog

I want to make OK button on my DatePickerDialog to open TimePickerDialog instead of just dismissing itself. How can I call the OK button on the DatePickerDialog to open a new dialog when finished instead of dismissing?

Answer (score 3):

You get a callback from `DatePickerDialog` when user presses "OK". You just need to override `onDateSet` method, and there do whatever stuff you want.

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker objPicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
      // open your second dialog or do anything you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `getButton` from `DatePickerDialog`.

Example:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(CalendarApp.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, mDateSetListerner, year, month, dayOfMonth);
dialog.show();

Button button1 = (Button) dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Oswal" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TodoList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```